# A solution to control multiple (Firefox) browsers simultaneously?

Tags: windows, browser, broadcasting

I'm looking for a Windows program/solution to broadcast actions (mouse movement & clicks, keyboard would be a plus) in real time to multiple browser windows. Best way to describe the functionality I'm after is something like Bluestacks with its sync feature, but in my case with regular desktop browsers instead of emulated android devices. The goal would be to have 20-50 "slave" browsers that receive inputs from a single "master" browser.

I have tried for a long time to find a program that does this, but so far I've not been able to find one. If such thing doesn't exist, I would also be interested to know if this sort of program would be possible/complicated/expensive to code from scratch, as I have no coding experience myself (except basic level python course at the uni). If it's not too complicated and expensive, I might be looking to hire someone to do it.

Edit: I'm not looking for recorded automation, or anything that involves code commands - just simple visual interface and effortless broadcasting across browsers.

All answers and any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Browser control is generally done with Selenium https://www.selenium.dev/. It's hard to give an exact answer without seeing specifically what you are trying to do but to be honest you are probably going about this the wrong way. There are not really "hand holding" methods to do this, it probably needs some code / GUI programming that talks to the POST endpoints / API's behind the browsers rather than the browsers themselves (but again you are not giving much information).

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answer! Someone else also pointed me towards selenium, so I guess that must be one of the keywords when I'm searching for a solution or someone to help me find one. 

As I mentioned I'm not a coder or developer, so I'm not even sure what kind of information would be helpful. I've seen that android emulators (Bluestacks) have a "Sync" or "Multibox" feature to control several emulated devices simultaneously, mirroring all actions - I'd need a similar thing but for desktop browser windows.

Comment: I understand it's a very niche solution/program I'm asking for and it probably doesn't readily exist - but as you have way better understanding than me: Is there any way to estimate how difficult/expensive it would be to hire a coder/company to do something like this? Thousands of dollars? Tens of thousands? More?